# NSInvalidArgumentException reason: data parameter is nil

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

When getting data from the server I get the following error:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException reason: data parameter is nil
```

Here is my code:

```
- (void)retrieveData
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://magmasysdev.com/ddc/getAllCompanies.php"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil]; // I'm getting error in this line
}
```

I want to store the following response in array:

```
[{"status":"Y"},{"company_data":[{"Company_Id":"5","Company_Name":"SANTE (PVT) LIMITED","Company_Address":"245\/2-Z P.E.C.H.S Block-6 \nKarachi-75400,Pakistan","Company_Email":"sante@sante.com.pk","Company_Tel_Num":"4520507, 4533425","Company_Website":"www.sante.com.pk","Company_Fax_Num":"4.54885e+006"}
```

Link to my web service : http://magmasysdev.com/ddc/getAllCompanies.php

Comment: i am getting follwing error "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'" means NSDATA is coming nil.. but whats the reason ?? i had mentioned my jsonrespose as well

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: how i am unable to understand ??

Comment: @MishalAwan There is no error in above three lines ,I execute above three lines it's working fine ! find out actual issue ,

Comment: @MishalAwan: error is happening from somewhere else, I'm getting response and the above codes working perfectly.

Comment: in my state it is not working and in my case i am getting this error in third line.. an din output window 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil' is shown and data = nil is shown.

Comment: R u using my url ???

Comment: Check you have the network connectivity in your device/simulator? may be proxy is blocking from accessing net

Comment: Its worked :) network connectivity issue... @anil will u please tell how to store coming data in dictionary .. ?

Comment: Its better to check you have a non nil `data` before doing a json parsing, otherwise you will end up in s crash. After json parsing you will get an array of dictionary objects.You may be interested in some objects only, that you can access by `jsonArray[0]` something like that. First see the response by logging jsonarray